# Sed Search and Replace

Tags: regex, search, replace, sed

I have a line in a file as follows:

```
LDAP_EXTERNAL_URL=ldap://server.domain.com:389
```

I need to replace everything after `//` with `server2.domain.com:399`

Start to get a headache with the regexp. Please advise.

Comment: Is it just this one line you need changed, or several lines with this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following as well if you're not strictly stuck on using sed.

```
perl -pe 's!^LDAP[^/]*//server\K.*!2.domain.com:399!' file
```

Comment: +1, always a treat to see your compact perl work. :) @Dan, if one of the answers work for you, please click the checkmark on the left as that is how the rep system works here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
sed -r 's|^(.*ldap://).*|\1server2.domain.com:339|' file
```

Ok to make it more complete:

```
sed -r 's|^(LDAP_EXTERNAL_URL=ldap://).*|\1server2.domain.com:339|' file
```

Add `-i` to enable inline editing.

Comment: Should work, but in my opinion, matching from `LDAP_EXTERNAL_URL` to `//` instead of just a `ldap://` URL could be more secure if there is only line to change. Of course in the end, it depends on OP's file content.